# Exponential of a sum comparing to a sum of exponentials (2 variables)

Tags: taylor-expansion, exponential-function, maxima-minima

I would like to prove for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ that $\dfrac{e^{x}+e^{y}}{2} \geq e^{\frac{x+y}{2}}$. My idea, is to show that $f(x,y) \ge 0$, it means that $(0,0)$ is the minimum of $f(x,y)$. So, I compute the equation: $\nabla f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\0 \end{pmatrix}$. I find that the solutions are $x=y$. **My first question is may I choose $\textbf{x=y=0}$?** After I have made this assumption, I compute the eigenvalues of $\nabla^2f(x,y)_{(0,0)}$ and got $\lambda_1=0$ and $\lambda_2=\dfrac{1}{2}$. Thus, I can't conclude anything about $(0,0)$ from this point since one of the eigenvalues is zero. **Do you have any idea about what can I do further using this method or a different path to prove it?** Thank you.

Comment: A very quick way would be to use the AM-GM inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Comment: Or think about the definition of a convex function.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$0 \le (e^{x/2}-e^{y/2})^2=e^x-2e^{\frac{x+y}{2}}+e^y$

Comment: Thank you! I shook my head when I saw that it takes one line to demonstrate it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting $e^x=u,e^y=v$, this is just

$$\frac{u+v}2\ge\sqrt{uv}.$$

---

Dividing by $e^x$ and setting $t:=y-x$,

$$\frac{1+e^t}2\ge e^{t/2}.$$

$$1+\frac t2+\frac{t^2}{2\,2!}+\frac{t^3}{2\,3!}+\cdots\ge1+\frac t2+\frac{t^2}{2^22!}+\frac{t^3}{2^33!}+\cdots$$